# VB.NET Addin How do I select current worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I'm trying to create an Excel VSTO Addin with VS2015 for a handful of VBA macros that I have.  I could do this using VBA, but want to get my feet wet in VB.NET.  The problem I'm facing though is how to get the active worksheet and assign it to a variable.  Then, I need to pass in a range that I converted to text previous.

The macro essentially enables a user to compare two lists of data by selecting the ranges and then highlighting items that appear in both lists.

[image]

Here's the code that executes when a user tries to select the range (works fine)

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Me.Hide()
        Dim R As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
        Dim A As String
        'note how the Application.InputBox brings up different settings to just InputBox
        R = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the reference range", Type:=8)
        A = R.Address
        Me.TextBox1.Text = A
        Me.Show()
        Me.TopMost = True
        Exit Sub

    Catch
        MsgBox("Please select a valid range!")
        Me.Show()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here's the code behind the "Search and Highlight" button, that should compare the two ranges and highlight duplicates.  However, when I run this it highlights cells in a different workbook, presumable the first one that I have open.  How do I make sure it's opening the current workbook that I'm operating in?

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim cell_1 As Excel.Range
    Dim cell_2 As Excel.Range
    Dim rng_1 As Excel.Range
    Dim rng_2 As Excel.Range

    xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    ws = xlApp.ActiveSheet
    sheetName = ws.Name

    rng_1 = ws.Range(Me.TextBox2.Text)
    rng_2 = ws.Range(Me.TextBox1.Text)

    For Each cell_1 In rng_1
        For Each cell_2 In rng_2
            If cell_2.Text = cell_1.Text Then
                cell_2.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

            End If
        Next cell_2
    Next cell_1

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, so I'm posting it for the next time I have to search for this. In the code below just make sure to change *ThisAddIn* to the name of your actual add-in.

```
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a workbook file name that you wish to interact with.

```
Dim ExcPro as New Excel.Application
Dim Excwrkbook as Excel.Workbook=ExcPro.Workbooks.Open("YoufileName")
```

`Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = Excwrkbook.ActiveSheet`

You can also iterate through the workbooks collection if it's already open if you know some details about the workbook such as its name.

```
Dim Exc_Books As Excel.Workbooks = Excpro.Workbooks
Dim Exc_book As Excel.Workbook = Exc_Books.Item(1)
```

Comment: What if you don't know anything about the workbook name?  I want to be able to use these functions in any workbook, not a specific one.  Is there a way to get the file name of the workbook that it's currently interacting with (or launched from)?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "ThisAddIn", what does that mean? Name of the solution file?

**Referring to your answer** posted on  Jun 8, 2017 at 16:54:

I found the answer, so I'm posting it for the next time I have to search for this. In the code below just make sure to change ThisAddIn to the name of your actual add-in.

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: `ThisAddIn` refers to the name of your add-in (or project).